# How do I turn my USB into a bootable device?

Tags: windows-7, data-recovery, mbr

So, I messed up my windows 7 boot loader, and I'm trying to change my USB so that I can use it as you would use the Windows Recovery disk. I have the .iso for the recovery disk and I've changed the file system of my USB drive to FAT32 and extracted the .iso to my USB, but I the USB drive is still not being recognized as bootable media.  I see plenty of guides for windows, but none for doing this on Ubuntu. I've tried changing the boot order in my BIOS, and it still doesn't work. How can I get my USB drive to act like the Windows Recovery Disk?

Comment: possible duplicated [How to create a Windows 8 bootable USB stick with Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/q/289559)

Answer (score 1):

You must use some program to extract the .iso and do the job. You can't make the USB dirve bootable by extracting it by yourself.

here's a ubuntu program that should do the trick http://www.ubuntugeek.com/winusb-simple-tool-that-enable-you-to-create-your-own-usb-stick-windows-installer.html#more-12922 (update: I noticed that it's the same program that's mentioned in Braiam's link)

You can also do it from windows if you have another computer, there are windows programs that can help too.